# What role did unique_ptr play in the creation of std::any

Tags: c++

In libcxx, the handler of `std::any` of a large object is created as:

```cpp
template <class ..._Args>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
static _Tp& __create(any & __dest, _Args&&... __args) {
    typedef allocator<_Tp> _Alloc;
    typedef allocator_traits<_Alloc> _ATraits;
    typedef __allocator_destructor<_Alloc> _Dp;
    _Alloc __a;

    unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> __hold(_ATraits::allocate(__a, 1), _Dp(__a, 1));
    _Tp * __ret = __hold.get();
    _ATraits::construct(__a, __ret, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);

    __dest.__s_.__ptr = __hold.release();
    __dest.__h_ = &_LargeHandler::__handle;
    return *__ret;
}
```

Why is the raw pointer is holding by a unique_ptr? Is it for safety in case an exception is thrown in the constructor?

I tried this, but the deconstructor is not invoked at all.

```cpp
struct A {
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    void* p;

    A() {
        p = malloc(50);
        std::cout << "constructing" << std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }

    ~A() {
        free(p);
        std::cout << "deconstructing " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::any a;

    try {
        __create(a);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It just allocates memory for the class. If exception is thrown in constructor then the memory will be deallocated. Since the class wasn't constructed, it cannot call a destructor on it.

Comment: Trying to create a local `A` instance would also output "constructing" but never output "deconstructing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just there to avoid having an explicit `try/catch` block if the constructor throws an exception. In that case, the memory needs to be deallocated. So rather than using a `try/catch` block, they just use RAII via `unique_ptr`.